# How to recursively set owner or permissions to 'everyone' for all folders and files?

Tags: macos, permissions

I have an external hard drive attached, and I need to set permissions to be 'free' for the user `MyUser`.

I think I need to set the owner to `MyUser` also.

How can I do this via terminal?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Find out the name of your external hard drive first, then navigate to:

```
cd /Volumes/your-drive/
```

Now, to give your current user ownership to all files:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) .
```

Or, alternatively

```
sudo chown -R MyUser .
```

That should allow you to do most operations, no need for any further modifications.

---

If you want to specifically have *write* permissions to all files and folders if they have been removed otherwise:

```
sudo chmod -R u+w .
```

And if you're really crazy and just want to give all permissions to everyone (as indicated by your title):

```
sudo chmod -R 777 .
```

But this shouldn't be necessary in most cases. Also, do note though that volumes with FAT32 file systems don't have that permissions concept.

In general, changing permissions like this on an external drive shouldn't be the solution to all of your problems though. Rather change the permissions based on a specific problem you face, for that particular folder only.

Comment: I should remember the command `sudo chown -R $(whoami)`, have to look it up every time

Comment: Be careful of the dot after chmod. Never ever ever run `sudo chmod -R 777 /` you will ruin everything

Comment: What the heck?  even with sudo I cannot change owner, permissions, or remove a system folder!

Comment: @ChrisM Is this on a new macOS release? Could be https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899

Comment: Yes, Catalina.  I found the solution on Reddit.  Disable SIP in Recovery Mode, then boot into Catalina and input into terminal `sudo mount -uw /`  This allowed me the "permissions" I needed to delete the folders.  This only lasts until reboot.  You then have to go back to recovery mode to reenable SIP.

Comment: Be careful since $(whoami) does not contain your group.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this with Terminal, but there's a simple way right from Finder.

Click on the drive in question [this works for any non-boot drive] &  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>i</kbd>  or right click > Get Info.

Click the padlock, bottom right & enter your admin password, then check the box marked 'Ignore ownership on this volume'.
Done.

[image]